# Is there a good standalone, lightweight, GUI-based Java debugging tool for the mac?

Tags: java, debugging, macos

I'm a CS student, so obviously IDEs are a bit of an overkill for me. I mainly code with Vim (well technically MacVim) and compile and run using the terminal. In the past I usually debug by using print statements. However I feel that it's time I move on to more appropriate tools for my need. I have heard of and tried jdb but I would prefer a GUI one. Any recommendations guys?

Comment: Mainly because we're only writing programs that are not more than a thousand lines, intended to run only in the terminal. Also during submissions we only need the source files. However if you can explain why using IDEs is indeed the way to go I'm more than happy to give it a go.

Comment: Do you intend to remain a CS student forever or do you plan on getting a job?  IDEs aren't overkill for Java any more than an electric saw is overkill for building a fence.  It's not just about editing, in modern programming you need to refactor, test, do code reviews, code coverage, etc. etc. So eclipse.org... please.

Comment: ... but if you think I'm being too snarky and you must use something vim like but better.  Use emacs with gdb for debugging.  I've used it in the past to debug java programs.  It's ok.

Comment: Yes, there are master woodworkers who refuse to use power tools.  And they can turn out some beautiful furniture, but starve because they can't produce enough to feed themselves.  "I don't use an IDE" would get you immediately disqualified in the hiring process at most places I've worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you're already extremely experienced with using another tool and love it to death, if you're doing Java, you should just use an IDE. You can go against the grain if you want, but I don't see the advantages for you. Eclipse and Netbeans are both free and excellent tools. It takes 2 minutes to create a new project thats ready to build/run with a single click. Syntax highlighting, refactoring, debugger, code completion are all things you will learn to love even if its a small program. If its complicated enough to need a debugger, its complicated enough to use an IDE.

Comment: Based on what everyone has to say I think I'll give Eclipse a try. What really sold it though is your last sentence.

Comment: This is a horrible answer if you're not developing a project (like, debugging a build containing a plugin with questionable behavior). This is about as silly as saying that the best way to develop a plugin for an IDE is to run the IDE twice - this is possible, but far from ideal, and just really bad design all around.

Comment: Sorry for necro-commenting @smaudet , but as someone who has developped IDE plugins, how else am I meant to develop IDE plugins other than having to instances of the IDE?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense @PiRocks - if you dev for a website you don't open a browser and then another browser. You can compile and run a program from a terminal - that's one way to do it.

Comment: An IDE is an optional way to develop, but its poor design in the sense that its non modular - can you swap out the editor or compiler on demand? Often the answer is "absolutely not". There's also the issue of opaque errors - there's a frequent issue where an error in one bit causes cascading issues in other areas (like VS or Eclispe or IntelliJ crashing because a bug in code corrupted the whole inst). All these things are normally responsibilties of the OS itself - often an IDE is a kludge for a bad or limited OS. Why reinvent the wheel? That's what an IDE does.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest **Eclipse for Java**.

Comment: that's a really old answer. Anyways, not much choice in Mac. Eclipse is still my pick. If you choose plug-ins carefully, Eclipse can be lightweight.